# Swift NSLocale programming constants

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization

is there a better way of coding this without using magic "en", "es" strings?

```
 let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
 if pre == "en"
    ....
  else if pre == "es"
    ....
  else if pre == "xx"
    ....
```

I was thinking to get compile time errors and not making a mistake this would be better

```
 let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
 if pre == NSLocale.something.ENGLISH
    ....
  else if pre == NSLocale.something.SPANISH
    ....
  else if pre == //and so on
    ....
```

but I cannot find anything.

Is this the right way to code?

Comment: You could make your own set of constants.

Comment: Make extension of Locale and make set of language with your language constant name.

Answer (score 0):

For the languages that you plan to support in your app, create an enum that maps the preferredLanguages to an enum case. The snipped below adds cases for english and Spanish.

```
// Create an enum that maps known language "Strings" to a case statement.
public enum LanguageMap : String{
    // Add a case for all the languages you app will support
    case English = "en"
    case Spanish = "es"
}
```

Extend `Locale` to add a property that will return an `[LanguageMap]` objects instead of `[String]`.

```
// Extend the Locale class to return

extension Locale{
    public static var preferredLanguageMap : [LanguageMap] {
        let langMap = Locale.preferredLanguages.flatMap({return LanguageMap.init(rawValue: $0) })
        return langMap
    }
}
```

In your application, replace the `if-else` statement with a switch case statement.

```
// Your application Logic.

switch Locale.preferredLanguageMap.first! {

case .English :
    print("Do Something the English Way")

case .Spanish :
    print("Do Something the Spanish Way")

default:
    print("Do Anything... Throw an error/Default Handling.")
    // Note : Locale.availableIdentifiers has 789 language identifiers till date.
    // This could also change in the future.
    // Ensure you have some default logic for all 'other languages' here.
}
```